# How to test Chainlink Operator.sol in Foundry and find cause of revert?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, foundry, forge

I am trying to rewrite [this test](https://github.com/EverID/everest-chainlink-consumer/blob/master/test/everest_consumer.js) from Truffle/Javascript to Foundry/Solidity.
This is the specific part I am stuck on:

```
 it("should not fulfill from unauthorized job", async function () {
                await expectRevert(
                    this.oracle.fulfillOracleRequest2(
                        ...oracle.convertFulfill2Params(
                            this.request,
                            responseTypes,
                            [kycUserStatus, nonZeroKycTimestamp],
                            { from: node }
                        )
                    ),
                    "Not authorized sender"
                );
            });
```

This is the test I have written  so far, with the relevant modifier above it:

```
modifier fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove() {
        vm.startPrank(msg.sender);
        LinkToken(_link).transfer(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.deal(REVEALER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE);
        vm.startPrank(REVEALER);
        LinkToken(_link).approve(address(everestConsumer), _oraclePayment);
        vm.stopPrank();
        _;
    }

function testRequestShouldNotFulfillFromUnauthorizedJob() public fundLinkToRevealerAndApprove {
        vm.startPrank(REVEALER);
        everestConsumer.requestStatus(REVEALEE);
        bytes32 requestId = everestConsumer.getLatestSentRequestId();
        uint8 kycUserStatus = 1;
        uint256 nonZeroKycTimestamp = 1658845449;
        bytes memory data = abi.encodePacked(requestId, kycUserStatus, nonZeroKycTimestamp);

        // vm.expectRevert("Not authorized sender");
        operator.fulfillOracleRequest2(
            requestId,
            _oraclePayment,
            address(everestConsumer),
            bytes4(keccak256("fulfill(bytes32,uint8,uint40)")),
            block.timestamp + 5 minutes,
            data
        );
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

When I type `forge test --mt testRequestShouldNotFulfillFromUnauthorizedJob -vvvv` I get this output:

```
[258872] EverestConsumerTest::testRequestShouldNotFulfillFromUnauthorizedJob() 
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [29652] LinkToken::transfer(REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], 1000000000000000000000 [1e21]) 
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38], to: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], amount: 1000000000000000000000 [1e21])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::deal(REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], 1000000000000000000000 [1e21]) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD]) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [24523] LinkToken::approve(EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 100000000000000000 [1e17]) 
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], spender: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], amount: 100000000000000000 [1e17])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD]) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [175066] EverestConsumer::requestStatus(REVEALEE: [0x50FA752360aD481DDbE824f39Cbc32FA9FD9458d]) 
    │   ├─ [20503] LinkToken::transferFrom(REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 100000000000000000 [1e17]) 
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], to: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], amount: 100000000000000000 [1e17])
    │   │   └─ ← true
    │   ├─ emit ChainlinkRequested(id: 0xb943d08a7488583c5b4f439538acbbd303a5c6cac670898915451e03d3b6aa7f)
    │   ├─ [57413] LinkToken::transferAndCall(Operator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], 100000000000000000 [1e17], 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) 
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], to: Operator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], amount: 100000000000000000 [1e17])
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], to: Operator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], value: 100000000000000000 [1e17], data: 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)
    │   │   ├─ [36029] Operator::onTokenTransfer(EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 100000000000000000 [1e17], 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) 
    │   │   │   ├─ [33725] Operator::operatorRequest(EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 100000000000000000 [1e17], 0x3530396538646438646530353464336639313836343061623061326237376438, 0xccd86824, 1, 2, 0x6761646472657373582000000000000000000000000050fa752360ad481ddbe824f39cbc32fa9fd9458d) [delegatecall]
    │   │   │   │   ├─ emit OracleRequest(specId: 0x3530396538646438646530353464336639313836343061623061326237376438, requester: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], requestId: 0xb943d08a7488583c5b4f439538acbbd303a5c6cac670898915451e03d3b6aa7f, payment: 100000000000000000 [1e17], callbackAddr: EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], callbackFunctionId: 0xccd86824, cancelExpiration: 301, dataVersion: 2, data: 0x6761646472657373582000000000000000000000000050fa752360ad481ddbe824f39cbc32fa9fd9458d)
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   └─ ← true
    │   ├─ emit Requested(_requestId: 0xb943d08a7488583c5b4f439538acbbd303a5c6cac670898915451e03d3b6aa7f, _revealer: REVEALER: [0x513dcA22893fBB7eB2C737A3b3D046d03D8371AD], _revealee: REVEALEE: [0x50FA752360aD481DDbE824f39Cbc32FA9FD9458d], _expiration: 301)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [624] EverestConsumer::getLatestSentRequestId() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0xb943d08a7488583c5b4f439538acbbd303a5c6cac670898915451e03d3b6aa7f
    ├─ [0] 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000::fulfillOracleRequest2(0xb943d08a7488583c5b4f439538acbbd303a5c6cac670898915451e03d3b6aa7f, 100000000000000000 [1e17], EverestConsumer: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 0xccd86824, 301, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062dff909) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← "EvmError: Revert"
```

I copied the Operator contract from Chainlink into its own mocks folder with all relevant imports and changed the compiler versions to 0.8.19 because Foundry wouldn't compile with it otherwise.
If I include the line `vm.expectRevert("Not authorized sender");` in my test or modify it to `vm.expectRevert();`, the output says `Call did not revert as expected`. So as far as I can tell the issue seems to be stemming from:

```
 operator.fulfillOracleRequest2(
            requestId,
            _oraclePayment,
            address(everestConsumer),
            bytes4(keccak256("fulfill(bytes32,uint8,uint40)")),
            block.timestamp + 5 minutes,
            data
        );
```

I have tried commenting out modifier and require lines in the Operator function like so:

```
function fulfillOracleRequest2(
        bytes32 requestId,
        uint256 payment,
        address callbackAddress,
        bytes4 callbackFunctionId,
        uint256 expiration,
        bytes calldata data
    )
        external
        override
            // validateAuthorizedSender
            // validateRequestId(requestId)
            // validateCallbackAddress(callbackAddress)
            // validateMultiWordResponseId(requestId, data)
        returns (
            bool
        )
    {
        // _verifyOracleRequestAndProcessPayment(requestId, payment, callbackAddress, callbackFunctionId, expiration, 2);
        emit OracleResponse(requestId);
        // require(gasleft() >= MINIMUM_CONSUMER_GAS_LIMIT, "Must provide consumer enough gas");
        // All updates to the oracle's fulfillment should come before calling the
        // callback(addr+functionId) as it is untrusted.
        // See: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#use-the-checks-effects-interactions-pattern
        (bool success,) = callbackAddress.call(abi.encodePacked(callbackFunctionId, data)); // solhint-disable-line avoid-low-level-calls
        return success;
    }
```

and still get `[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert]` or `[FAIL. Reason: Call did not revert as expected]` depending on if I include `vm.expectRevert();`.
I'd be very grateful for any help in solving this. Thanks!

Comment: From my observation, it seems that the use of `staticcall` has altered the context of `msg.sender` to `address(0)`. As a result, the test has failed, in my opinion because `fulfillOracleRequest2` function is being called by `address(0)`, which is unexpected. This issue can sometimes occur in Foundry when `staticcalls` and pranks are combined. However, I believe that this issue can be resolved by commenting out the `everestConsumer.getLatestSentRequestId()` call and passing `requestId` as a constant instead.